# from pyramid.arima import auto_arima not working

Tags: pandas, time-series, forecasting, pyramid-arima

I am doing some timeseries forecasting, while at it I am trying to import auto_arima using pyramid but it throws an Module not found error as - ''No module named 'pyramid.arima'

```
from pyramid.arima import auto_arima
```

I also tried importing auto_arima from pmdarima :

```
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
```

but this throws an error as - 
"type object 'pmdarima.arima._arima.array' has no attribute '**reduce_cython**'"

What am I doing wrong?...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `pmdarima` package without any issues, but your error is highly probably related to your numpy version. I would recommend to you to upgrade it (in case you use `pip`):

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

You can also try to import `numpy` package before importing `auto_arima` (some people experience strange behavior).

You can follow discussion on github issues - https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima/issues/91 (similar [here](https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima/issues/144) or [here](https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima/issues/143)). You're definitely not the first one with that issue.

If it doesn't help, please, paste your `pmdarima` and `numpy` versions.